# Vertically centring text in a block level HTML element

Tags: html, css, alignment

i got a question about how to center a text inside a div in html / css.
I have a h3 tag like this

```
<h3>Pacuraru Daniel Pacuraru Daniel</h3>
or
<h3>Pacuraru Daniel</h3>
```

and the css

```
h3 {
width: 100%;
height: 28px;
display: block;
}
```

If I have a name longer than 1 line, then the 2 lines of the text fit in the div, but if there is only 1 line, I want it to be vertically centered not aligned on top.

EDIT: i have this layout and i want in the both divs the text to be centered vertically
http://jsfiddle.net/shRRz/3/

Comment: Take a look at this: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/css-asylum/css-vertical-text-alignment-31790

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that? What were the specific problems with your solution?

Comment: the problem is more complex because i have this tag in a table layout and on the 1st column i have a picture and on this 2nd column i have the text which should be aligned inline with the avatar, but the text will always align on the bottom of the avatar

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do it. It seems i need to use this css to make it align like i wanted.

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Thank you very much for the tips, people.